# Capture logs (errors, warnings) in exported/deployed OSX app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am exporting my app as a .app and testing it on different OSX versions and machines. Is there any way to capture warnings, errors, etc. to a log?

The application is not crashing so a crash log is not being generated.

Comment: did any of the below link help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to capture these is using something similar to [TestFairy](https://testfairy.com) (framework for android / ios beta testing), I suggest you take a look at that, to see what functionalities it provides and the search for something similar on mac os.

Found these two for Mac :

- [hockeyapp](http://hockeyapp.net/features/)
- [plccrashreporter](https://plcrashreporter.org/)